# How to set a home body class background image to load random images from predetermined directory

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to make my wordpress site load a different background image on the homepage every time I refresh the page.

The site is http://americasfinestlighting.com

I would like to add a function to my functions.php file or add a script to my home.php file.

I am curently loading the home page background image with the following css

```
body.home {
    background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background1.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The other images I would like the site to load randomly are in the images/home-bg directory.

Thanks, 
William

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display random image when page loads without utilizing onload in the body tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777479/display-random-image-when-page-loads-without-utilizing-onload-in-the-body-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_filter('body_class','random_background_images');
function random_background_images($classes) {

    // Generate Random number from 1 to 10.  
    $background_class = 'background_' . rand(1,10);

    $classes[] = $background_class;

    return $classes;
}
```

Add the code above to your wordpress themes functions.php file.

It will add a random body class from `background_1`   to `background_10`

now you can add css for them as you want.

```
    body.background_1 {
       background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background1.jpg");
    }
    body.background_2 {
       background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background2.jpg");
    }
    body.background_3 {
       background-image: url("images/home-bg/website-background3.jpg");
    }
```

Just like this.  Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: This worked great. The only tweak I needed to make was changing the body.background_1 to body.home.background_1 so it would only load on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get all the files in the directory like so make sure to exclude . and .. they will be returned by readdir.

```
while (false !== ($filename = readdir("images/home-bg"))) {
    if ($filename != '.' && $filename != '..')    
        $files[] = $filename;
}
```

Then get a random key like this from the files array (There is a possibility you get the same in a row)

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($files, 1);
```

Then with your key you can get the value from the the files array.

```
$files[$rand_keys[0]]
```

When you put it all together you get this

```
function getRandomImage(){

    while (false !== ($filename = readdir("images/home-bg"))) {
        if ($filename != '.' && $filename != '..')    
            $files[] = $filename;
    }

    $rand_keys = array_rand($files, 1);

    return $files[$rand_keys[0]]
}
```

Now where you want to set the actual background image that is up to you. You will have to place `echo 'background-image: url("images/home-bg/'.getRandomImage().'")';` some where.

Comment: Thanks for help. Where would you recommend echoing the background image? Can I do that from my function file? Do I need to change anything in my css file?

Comment: You can't echo in a CSS file only in php files. The easiest way is to just do it in your php file that contains the element you will assign the background image to. I have no experience with Wordpress but i guess the html is in php file so just change `<body class="home blog header-image header-full-width full-width-content" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" style="">` to `<body class="home blog header-image header-full-width full-width-content" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" style="<?php echo 'background-image: url("images/home-bg/'.getRandomImage().'")'; ?>">`

Comment: Had no more room in the comment and then make sure you also have the function in the same file for obvious reasons.