# How to change the CSS of an HTML element with the output of a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to make a page [display a random image on load like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777479/display-random-image-when-page-loads-without-utilizing-onload-in-the-body-tag) in the future, but instead of returning a "**< img src="image.png" >**" to be added with "**document.write(imageTag())**", I would like to use a **setAttribute()** or **element.style.backgroundImage()** to change the CSS of a div block I have set aside with the output of a random image Javascript function.

---

For instance, I am trying to change the background-color of a simple div block, in order to "change the css with the output of a Javascript function." (original question)

html:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("coloredBlock").style.backgroundColor = color();
  </script>
```

CSS:

```
#coloredBlock {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function color(){
return "purple";
}
```

The output I am looking for is for that block to be purple. A [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qyVGGw) of what I mean.

---

Also, my setAttribute() doesn't seem to work, only element.style:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("coloredBlock").style.backgroundColor = "green";
  </script>
```

works and the block turns green, but

```
<script>
document.getElementById("coloredBlock").setAttribute('background-color', 'blue')
  </script>
```

does not work and the block remains yellow.

---

I am certain the answer has something to do with how  "  document.getElementById("coloredBlock").style.backgroundColor = color();
" is written.

Comment: Your codepen errors with _"color is not defined"_. Seems your JS isn't getting included, at least, not in the right place. This is because Codepen is putting the contents of the _"JS"_ tab at the **end** of your document

Comment: Here it is fixed ~ https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bjYPbW. Next time, check your console for errors

Comment: FYI, `background-color` is not an HTML attribute. If you wanted to use `setAttribute()`, it would be `setAttribute('style', 'background-color: blue')`